# kubectl set image deployment not working on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubectl

No matter what I do I can't get to work with **Jenkins**, it works perfectly on my local machine but when i run this command on Jenkins the deployment not get updated (`pods` stay the same).

I've tried `kubectl apply -f`  but it still doesn't work.

any ideas ?

Comment: kubectl set image deployment/website website=gcr.io/XXX-1/website:$1 return no error on jenkins, but the pod not get updated